# How to write correctly in a heading the genus and species name of a microorganism?

Tags: capitalization, writing-style, technical, taxonomy

I have a question regarding how to write correctly the name of a microorganism in the title of my thesis when using letters in uppercase:

Option A:

> ...BLAH...BLAH... *ESCHERICHIA COLI* ...BLAH...BLAH... .

Option B:

> ...BLAH...BLAH... *Escherichia coli* ...BLAH...BLAH... .

I guess option B is the most correct in this case. Is that right?

---

I've searched for an answer to this question and I've found this [link](http://www.highveld.com/microbiology/the-correct-way-to-write-ecoli.html) that says that one should never capitalise names of organisms in titles or headings. I asked two worldwide recognised microbiologists: Alan Bull and Michel Goodfellow and they told me that a correct way of writing names of organisms in headings is as in option B: that's the norm and scientifically correct. In my thesis title, I decided to go for option B.

Comment: I think this question asks (and answers) a specific and unusual style question (about handling species names in titles) that future users may find quite helpful. I think it should be reopened.

Comment: I absolutely agree with Sven Yargs. I also think this question should be reopened, since there is no relevant information on the web in this regard. The answers given to this question could be a source of useful information for students and people from academia.

Comment: isn't this a matter for a style guide?

Comment: Essentially, the scientific community would say that IUPAC pronouncements trump the lesser rules and conventions of muggles (non-Scientists). While teaching, I came across the inane situation where students would lose a mark for spelling _sulphur_ 'sulphur' in science, but would lose a mark for spelling it 'sulfur' in English essays. // This is not a question for ELU to pronounce upon. Why use capitals for the title? If you've been instructed to by somebody, ask **them** to decide. Then let us know. But it's quite possible that the next person with this problem will be advised differently.

Answer (score 1):

Your question ventures deep into the territory of style issues—where choices are a matter of preference, not of objective right and wrong. Nevertheless, I think it's an interesting question.

If you're running the title in all-uppercase letters, it seems to me, you have already adopted a rather unorthodox title style. That being the case, you are operating outside the ambit of most style guides and are free to deal with the scientific name *Escherichia coli* as you see fit.

My preference, if the rest of the title is to appear in roman all-caps, would be to render it in italic all-caps. I can't think of any rationale for suddenly switching from all-caps to standard in-text genus-and-species form for a scientific name—just as it would seem odd to switch from all-caps to upper and lower case for *Democratic Republic of the Congo* in the midst of a bunch of all-cap BLAH BLAH BLAHS. So I would recommend following your option A above in this case:

> BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH *ESCHERICHIA COLI* BLAH BLAH

If you are working in normal title case, where articles (definite and indefinite) and short prepositions are lowercased, I would be inclined to follow scientific style rather than word-based uppercasing conventions in the title (that is, I would favor *Escherichia coli* over *Escherichia Coli* in the title). That would yield this result:

> Blah Blah Blah Blah *Escherichia coli* Blah Blah

In scientific journals, it is quite common to render titles of articles and papers in sentence style, which gives you a third option and a third issue to resolve: cap *Escherichia* or lowercase it? Since the genus name appears in scientific names as if it were a proper noun, it makes sense to me to capitalize it even in a sentence-case setting:

> Blah blah blah blah *Escherichia coli* blah blah

Regrettably, I couldn't dig up a discussion of this particular issue in the style guides I consulted, although it must come up now and then. The closest thing to a relevant suggestion that I could find was this tangentially related item from *The Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003):

> **17.157** *Italics and quotation marks within article titles.* Book titles and other normally italicized terms remain italicized within an article title. ...
>
> [Relevant example:] Connell, A. D., and D. D. Alrey. 1982. The chronic effects of fluoride on the estuarine amphipods *Grandidierella lutosa* and *G. lignorum*. *Water Research* 16: 1313–17.

This example (which appears in a discussion of how to present a journal article in documentation) makes clear that, under *Chicago* style, scientific names are italicized in otherwise nonitalicized titles, and that the genus name remains initial-capped in a sentence-style title. In other respects, however, the example doesn't help much with the particular questions you raise.

Comment: Hello, Sven Yargs. I've searched for an answer to this question and I've found this [link](http://www.highveld.com/microbiology/the-correct-way-to-write-ecoli.html) that says that one should never capitalise names of organisms in titles or headings.

I asked two worldwide recognised microbiologists: Alan Bull and Michel Goodfellow and they told me that a correct way of writing names of organisms in headings is as in option B: that's is the norm and scientifically correct.

In my thesis title, I decided to go for option B.

Thanks.

Comment: @user2292533: Your comment contains useful information for future readers who may have the same question you did. I recommend that you copy your comment here and paste it into your original question as a followup paragraph. Comments tend to disappear unexpectedly and without fanfare, but questions and answers (even closed ones) do not, as long as they aren't deleted. I appreciate your having done further research on your own to obtain more-accurate information about how things are done in the field of microbiology. +1 to your question for your extra effort—and success—in this regard.

Comment: Sorry about the edit. I hadn't realized that the OP was writing the thesis  title in block capitals, which I think is odd. Maybe you want to rollback the edit or modify the examples. (they are fewer *BLAHS*)

Comment: That's OK. I know that it is a bit odd that the title is written is capitals, but it's the format that I've been told to use. I agree with your edit, but I deleted the italics in the BLAHs because that will convert my question in something that I did not want to ask.